# How to shorten Comparator with multiple fields?

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, comparator

I am trying to write a Comparator in java8 which depends on two criteria with the use of lambda. I have a `List` persons. A `Person` has this methods:

```
Person{
   String getFirstName();
   String getLastName();
   int getHeight();
   Date getBirthday();
}
```

The sorting of the list is depending on two criterias which can be chosen by will. So it could be that the list should be sorted be firstname and birthday or by firstname and height and so on.

My approach was to create a switch-case block in which I look at the different combinations of criteria. But this approach is getting too big.

```
switch (holder.criteria1) {
        case FIRSTNAME:
            switch (holder.criteria2) {
                case FIRSTNAME:
                    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName,
                            Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo)));
                    break;
                case LASTNAME:
                    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstname,
                            Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo)).thenComparing(
                            Person::getLastName, Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo)));
                    break;
                case HEIGHT:
                    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstname,
                            Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo)).thenComparing(
                            Person::getHeight, Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compareTo)));
                    break;
                case BIRTHDAY:
                    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstname,
                            Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo)).thenComparing(
                            Person::getBirthday, Comparator.nullsFirst(Date::compareTo)));
                    break;
            }
            break;
```

I have to repeat this for every case combination. Three out of four cases of the criteria2 are nearly the same, only the methodnames and types change. This is a very ugly and long code and I would like to re-design it in a better way.

Is there a way to shorten this by using reflection perhaps?

Comment: Please don't introduce reflection just to try to shorten code.

Comment: Create one comparator for each criteria, and supply the correct comparator depending on the chosen option.

Comment: shouldn't the second switch be switching on ```holder.criteria2``` or something?

Comment: This is a good example for the "tell don't ask principle". You don't query the criteria and then decide on how to sort; instead you should change your code so that a "criteria" knows how to sort. Besides: not only are such enum switches long and ugly ... you should avoid them completely.

Comment: @JornVernee yes, you're right. I edited my question.

Comment: @Jägermeister yes, you're right too. I edited the question, it wasn't phrased very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the comparators in your enum values, and then combine on demand:

```
enum SortOn {
    FIRSTNAME(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName,
        Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo))),
    LASTNAME(Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName, 
        Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo))),
    HEIGHT(Comparator.comparing(Person::getHeight, 
        Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compareTo))),
    BIRTHDAY(Comparator.comparing(Person::getBirthday, 
        Comparator.nullsFirst(Date::compareTo)));

    public final Comparator<Person> comparator;

    private SortOn(Comparator<Person> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }
}
...
public void sort(SortOn criteria1, SortOn criteria2) {
    if(criteria1 == criteria2) {
        list.sort(criteria1.comparator);
    } else {
        list.sort(criteria1.comparator.thenComparing(criteria2.comparator));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe you coud do it that way:

```
public enum Holder{
 FIRSTNAME{
   @override
    Function getFunction(){
     return Person::getFirstName;
    }
}

 ........
 abstract Function getFunction();
}
```

Then you just need this call:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(holder1.getFunction(),
                          Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo)).thenComparing(
                        holder2.getFunction(), Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo)));
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to [Jorn Vernee’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37133552/2711488), here a derived variant with avoids the code duplication:

```
enum SortOn {
    FIRSTNAME(Person::getFirstName),
    LASTNAME(Person::getLastName),
    HEIGHT(Person::getHeight),
    BIRTHDAY(Person::getBirthday);

    public final Comparator<Person> comparator;

    private <U extends Comparable<U>> SortOn(Function<Person,U> f) {
        this.comparator = Comparator.comparing(f,
            Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
    }
    private SortOn(ToIntFunction<Person> f) {
        this.comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(f);
    }
}
```

Since all properties have a `Comparable` type, they can be treated similarly, when their *natural order* is desired.

While they all could work the same, the `HEIGHT` instance uses an alternative constructor here to create a `Comparator` specific to `int` properties that avoids the boxing overhead. Since these values can never be `null`, the `null`-check is also obsolete for this specific property.

This enumeration still can be used the same way, e.g.

```
public static void sort(List<Person> list, SortOn criteria1, SortOn criteria2) {
    if(criteria1 == criteria2) {
        list.sort(criteria1.comparator);
    } else {
        list.sort(criteria1.comparator.thenComparing(criteria2.comparator));
    }
}
```

or supporting an arbitrary number of criteria:

```
public static void sort(List<Person> list, SortOn... criteria) {
    list.sort(Arrays.stream(criteria).map(c -> c.comparator)
        .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("no criteria given")));
}
```